# Why do my files have a gray X on them?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

In Windows Vista, one particular folder and its files have a gray X icon on them. They are from a zip file I downloaded from the Internet (a Wordpress theme). If I copy a file to a different folder the X vanishes.

There doesn't seem to be any restrictions on the files - I can still edit them perfectly fine. Here is an enlarged view of the files in Explorer:

[image: Windows Explorer]

Comment: Do you have TortoiseSVN or TortoiseHg or similar installed? Those look a bit like the overlays you get with some source version control tools, for "working copy" folders. Best guess - these are unversioned files (not in the repository that the working copy relates to).

Comment: @Steve314: Yes, I do have TortoiseSVN installed. While I investigate, maybe you should post that as an answer ;)

Comment: This is related to network file availability I believe. I don't know a better answer though. TortoiseSVN re-uses the built-in Windows icon overlay for its own purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those look a bit like the overlays you get with some source version control tools, such as TortoiseSVN, for "working copy" folders. Best guess - these are unversioned files (not in the repository that the working copy relates to).

One way you could get a working copy without knowing about it - the zip may hold a working copy - a subversion working copy is a folder with some extra stuff in hidden ".svn" folders, and that hidden stuff can survive being zipped. However, that seems unlikely - you'd expect the files to be versioned within the working copy.

Comment: I turned on the options to show hidden files and protected OS files but there is no .svn folder in there. EDIT: I also have Dropbox installed and I may have copied the files from my Dropbox folder...

Comment: Not having a .svn folder is wierd. AFAIK that's what defines a working copy. However, Tortoise does do some caching which can get confused - you could check that. Also, you could install SlikSVN (command-line subversion) and see what it says.